# Uploading a file to google drive from appengine (python)

Tags: google-app-engine, google-drive-api

I'm trying to upload a file to google drive from google app engine. 
I have tried 2 different ways but I lose information in both.

The first one is the next one:

-The html form:

```
<html><body><form id='myForm' method='post' action='/guardar' 
    enctype='multipart/form-data' >
<input type="file" id="doc" name="doc" >
<input type="submit" value="Enviar"></form>
</body></html>
```

-The python code:

```
class guardar(webapp.RequestHandler):

  @decorator.oauth_required

  def post(self):      

  http = decorator.http()

  service = build('drive', 'v2', http=http)

  thefile = self.request.get('doc')

  media_body = MediaInMemoryUpload(thefile, mimetype='text/plain', resumable=True)

  response = service.files().insert(body={'title': 'prueba_si','mimeType': 'text/plain'},media_body=media_body).execute()
```

This way I lose the mimetype of the uploaded file and the title too; and I need both.

I have tried this other way but it always says that such file does not exist:

-The html file:

```
<html><body><form id='myForm' method='post' action='/guardar' >
<input type="file" id="doc" name="doc" >

<input type="submit" value="Enviar"></form>

</body></html>
```

-The python code:

```
class guardar(webapp.RequestHandler):

  @decorator.oauth_required

  def post(self):      

  http = decorator.http()

  service = build('drive', 'v2', http=http)

  thefile = self.request.get('doc')

  mime_type=mimetypes.guess_type(thefile,strict=True)
    media_body = MediaFileUpload(filename, mimetype=mime_type, resumable=True)
  response = service.files().insert(body={'title': 'prueba_si','mimeType': mime_type},media_body=media_body).execute()
```

Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to pass the mime type in the media upload and also in the metadata. I would leave it just in the media upload.

You should not lose the title information, but I cannot reproduce your error.

Comment: Yeah, that's true, only in one is enough. And If I had the title with the extension I wouldn't need to put it neither, but I don't see the error.
Thank you anyway!